# Android XML Layout Layering

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Is there a generally accepted way of doing this? My home screen initially looked like the below image, using the below code, to prompt the user to start a game.

[Original home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zQCC.jpg)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.snake.SnakeView
     android:id="@+id/snake"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tileSize="24" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="@string/snake_layout_text_text"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#ff8888ff"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This worked with no errors, but I needed to add items for user input (EditText) and show last 5 scores (Button) and wanted this prompt below it rather than putting the player through multiple screens. From what I've read, I should be able to embed a FrameLayout inside a RelativeLayout with no conflicts, but it only works to the Show Scores button and the game prompt is missing. When I check it in design view, I am also now getting an error that the bottom half (which is now showing) is failing to instantiate the class that would allow the game to play. I am simply beside myself on how to correct this and would like to understand what I have done wrong so as to not allow this to happen again on future projects. Below is the modified code that causes the errors.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username"
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Last 5 Games"
        android:id="@+id/btnLastFive"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.example.android.snake.SnakeView
        android:id="@+id/snake"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tileSize="24" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#ff8888ff"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Proposed layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg8zw.jpg)

Comment: So, you want to have a layout that looks exactly like the proposed layout? Or what you want is when clicking on the big blue label "Snake press up to play" to show the proposed layout?

Comment: Yes. The proposed layout is what the design view currently show in Android Studio. The home screen, in theory, should appear exactly the like the proposed with the bottom half displaying what was shown in the original.

Comment: Ok. What's in `com.example.android.snake.SnakeView` (reference to "I am also now getting an error that the bottom half (which is now showing) is failing to instantiate the class that would allow the game to play.")? And another question, When the user clicks on "press up to play" the label should disappear and let only the `com.example.android.snake.SnakeView` be shown, right?

Comment: SnakeView is the class that actually controls the game functions. Since the class is failing to be instantiated, the game is not able to be played. Press up to play is what initializes the game to begin inside the SnakeView class, when this happens, the home screen is replaced by the actual game board.

Comment: Understood, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the namespace of the custom view `com.example.android.snake.SnakeView` on your root layout, and add the namespace prefix before the declaration of your custom Views attributes.

So assuming the namespace is "app", `tileSize` becomes for example `app:tileSize`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    ......

    <com.example.android.snake.SnakeView
        android:id="@+id/snake"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:tileSize="24" />

    .....

</LinearLayout>
```

It also seems that you have removed the text content "Snake Press up to play" from your TextView `@+id/text`, otherwise you won't be able to see it.

Comment: I added your suggestions, but the bottom half of the screen still fails to load/instantiate the SnakeView class. Also, the text content for press up is part of a method in SnakeView, not a hardcoded text, as this can be one of multiple screens, the press up to play is simply the one I had a SS of.

Comment: Yes, I verified in AS just to be certain nothing got changed accidentally.

Comment: Remove the content of all "build" folders on AS, then "make project", "clean project", "rebuild project", "run app", if it's still not working could you share if possible the `com.example.android.snake.SnakeView.java` code?

Comment: I hope codeshare is an acceptable way to do this. If not, I will add the code to the original post, it's just a lengthy file and I want to keep things clean.  https://codeshare.io/5Mex0R

Comment: Sure, no worries, from the code I see that I'll also need `TileView.java` and the `attrs.xml` you're using (you can update the same codeshare)
also, post the exception stacktrace you get

Comment: @KayAna your code isn't failing at the layout level, it's failing at this line `sounds = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);` the reason why you don't see a meaningful exception is because you're targeting the SDK 26 for which you haven't yet installed the sources, so now just downgrade to 25 on your gradle script and see what exception you get (post it on the same codeshare)

Comment: That is odd, the sounds worked fine before I made the changes to the layout and its supporting code

Comment: From the exception stacktrace: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
 at android.media.SoundPool.<init>(SoundPool.java:32)
 at com.example.android.snake.SnakeView.loadSound(SnakeView.java:342)
 at com.example.android.snake.SnakeView.<init>(SnakeView.java:142)
`

Comment: From the source the error message is "Native setup failed". I don't know this API but From a SO answer, try to replace the first constructor argument by 5. If that doesn't work replace that line by `AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder ().setContentType (AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION).setFlags (AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED).setUsage (AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_COMMUNICATION_INSTANT).build ();
sounds = new SoundPool.Builder ().setMaxStreams (5).setAudioAttributes (attributes).build ();`
(Also test from a physical device not the emulator)

Comment: To save a bit of time, I simply commented out every reference to the sounds. The XML still fails to instantiate on the SnakeView class, it's just a different error. I updated the codeshare file.